# Session.SetString method throws exception "IFeatureCollection has been disposed. Object name: 'Collection'. " in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a project written in ASP.NET Core 3.1.

I need to set data to Session in Singleton service:

```
 _session.SetString("some key", "some value");
```

I injected the session object from DI:

```
public OperatorService(ILogger<OperatorService> logger, 
                       ISession session,
                       IOptions<AppSettings> options)
{
     this._session = session; 
     this._logger = logger; 
     this._appSettings = options.Value;
}
```

I calls the my method as below:

```
public void ChangeOperatorStatus(StatusChangeRequest request)
{
     try
     {
         _session.SetString(request.Key, request.Value);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          _logger.LogInformation($"Exception while changing status: {ex}"); 
     } 
}
```

but I get the exception below :

```
IFeatureCollection has been disposed.\r\nObject name: 'Collection'.
```

and I added some code to Startup.cs's ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
})
.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
```

And I added `app.UseSession();` to the Configure method of Startup.cs.

I trid  `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();` and I get the session from  `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session` but I get the same error.

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Where do you get that exception?

Comment: This is a closed issue in github. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14841

Comment: @John  in   _session.SetString(SessionKeys.UserStatus, "some value");

Comment: @RamilAliyev Elvin's link shows that the problem was caused by incorrect use of `HttpContextAccessor`. You *still* haven't posted where the error occurs. WHere is that `_session.SetString(SessionKeys.UserStatus, "some value");`? Where did that `_session` come from, especially in a *Singleton*?

Comment: An HttpContext is the context of a *single* request. It provides access to the request, response properties etc of that single request. You can't cache it, it becomes invalid once that request ends.

Comment: Why are you using the session in a *singleton*? Sessions are per user, you need to know which user/request you're working with. Please post your code. Where is the session retrieved and cached?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos _session.SetString(SessionKeys.UserStatus, "some value"); is in written method of singleton service, which i get the session from DI in constructor of that singleton service

Comment: Post that code then! That's what causes the bug. Sessions are per user, whose session is the Singleton trying to access? To get that `_session` you had to use a transient requests's HttpContext as a singleton, which leads to that error

Comment: You  could use a Scoped service instead of a Singleton, which would make `IHttpContextAccessor` point to the correct request context.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i already edited.

Comment: @RamilAliyev where does that `ISession` come from? The bug is clear - the code tries to use an expired session. So you need to find out where that expired session comes from. If `OperatorService` is a Singleton, it's guaranteed to have the *wrong* session once a second user hits the site. `AddSession` doesn't registger `ISession` with the DI, so where did it come from?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i added services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
})
.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); to ConfigureServices and app.UseSession(); to Configure method of Startup.cs . Doesn't the session come from here?

Comment: No it doesn't. You added it somewhere else. `AddSession` doesn't even registger `ISession` with the dependency injection services. How do you create `OperatorService` ? And why is it a Singleton instead of a Scoped service? Post the code that registers or creates OperatorService and the code that uses it. That's what needs fixing

Comment: Although I already answered with the possible fixes - make OperatorService a Scoped service so it can get the correct HttpContext, or make `ISession` a parameter of `ChangeOperatorStatus` so callers can pass the correct session

Comment: I create OperatorService  from DI in controller's constructor.  OperatorService  implemented from IOperatorService and binded it the as below: services.AddSingleton<IOperatorService , OperatorService  >(); @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: i can't that the service to scoped, because as it provides other services during the project working, therefore that must be singleton ((

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An HttpContext is the context of a single request. It provides access to the request, response properties etc of that single request. You can't cache it, it becomes invalid once that request ends.

Session is another transient thing - it lives only as long as a single user session. There's at least one session for every user of a web app. Caching one of those sessions in a singleton guarantees that

- The reference will become invalid after a while, when the session expires and
- The singleton will use only that user's values, ignoring everyone else's. This is a bug in itself, and a *great* way to hack into an application.
- If an administrator logs in, the Session object may apply the admin's settings alive to everyone for the next 20, 30 or 60 minutes.

That's why using a Session makes sense for per-request middleware, not Singleton services.

**Correct usage of HttpContext**

The Session can only be reached through the request's context, so getting the correct session means getting the correct HttpContext. The correct way to do this is explained in [David Fowler's ASP.NET Core Guidance](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AspNetCoreGuidance.md#do-not-store-ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-a-field) :

> ❌ BAD This example stores the HttpContext in a field then attempts to use it later.

```
    private readonly HttpContext _context;
    public MyType(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _context = accessor.HttpContext;
    }
    public void CheckAdmin()
    {
        if (!_context.User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("The current user isn't an admin");
        }
    }
```

> ✅ GOOD This example stores the IHttpContextAccesor itself in a field and uses the HttpContext field at the correct time (checking for null).

```
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
   public MyType(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
   {
       _accessor = accessor;
   }

   public void CheckAdmin()
   {
       var context = _accessor.HttpContext;
       if (context != null && !context.User.IsInRole("admin"))
       {
           throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("The current user isn't an admin");
       }
   }
```

**Use a Scoped service instead**

Since a Singleton can't know what session to use. One option is to simply convert that service to a Scoped service. In ASP.NET Core, a request defines a scope. That's how controller actions and pipeline middleware get access to the correct HttpContext for each request.

Assuming the service is used by an action or middleware, perhaps the only change needed is to replace `AddSingleton<ThatService>` with `AddScoped<ThatService>`

**Turning the tables, or Inversion of Control**

Another option is for *callers* of that singleton should provide the session to it. Instead of using a cached session eg  :

```
public void SetStatus(string status)
{
    _session.SetString(SessionKeys.UserStatus, "some value");
}
```

Ask for the session or HttpContext as a parameter :

```
public void SetStatus(string status,ISession session)
{
    session.SetString(SessionKeys.UserStatus, "some value");
}
```

And have callers pass the correct session to it

Answer (score 3):

It took me a while to get this fixed.
In my case, it was a 3.1 aspnetcore and it didn't worked until I turn the container function from

`public async void OnPost`

to

`public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost`

Looks like the HttpContext was disposed before it was used...

Comment: Because you cannot use await keyword for async void method. Therefore you must use async Task instead of async void