# How Can I Fix this error: 'IFeatureCollection has been disposed. in Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, model-view-controller

How can I fix this error:

> 'IFeatureCollection has been disposed. in Asp.net Core MVC

I used Filesystem Watcher to get Event Data of files in Path
all works fine and I  send trace in database but Adminid and roleid which they are session values caused this problem when I tried to use them in `OnChanged` Method

This is my controller:

```cs
public IActionResult RHManager()
{
    ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
    ViewBag.RoleCreateur = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("role_id").ToString());
    var Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
    
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

    //Mention the Path that you want to monitor file events.

    watcher.Path = @"\\100.100.1.6\drh-m$";
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes |
    NotifyFilters.CreationTime |
    NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |
    NotifyFilters.FileName |
    NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
    NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
    NotifyFilters.Security |
    NotifyFilters.Size;
    watcher.Filter = "*.*";
    //File System Events to listen them
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

    // Starting monitoring the folder.
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    return View(watcher);
}

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    TraceFileManager trace = new TraceFileManager();
    trace.Time = DateTime.Now;
    trace.Adminid = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
    trace.Roleid = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
    trace.Changedfile = e.Name;
    trace.Seen = false;
    trace.Etat = "En attente";
    trace.Changetype = e.ChangeType.ToString();
    _context.Add(trace);
    
    _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session.SetString method throws exception "IFeatureCollection has been disposed. Object name: 'Collection'. " in ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59963383/session-setstring-method-throws-exception-ifeaturecollection-has-been-disposed)

Answer (score 3):

Scoped services are disposed at the request's end.
The main problem is `OnChanged` can be called after the request's end.
When you need a scoped service outside a request, you need inject `IServiceScopeFactory` and use it to get service.

Idem, when the property `ControllerBase.HttpContext` is called in `OnChanged`.
But, it isn't possible to get HttpContext outside a request.
Then, you need geed information from HttpContext in the request and set in `OnChanged` call.

```cs
public RhController : ControllerBase
{
    private IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public RhController(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public IActionResult RHManager()
    {
        ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
        ViewBag.RoleCreateur = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("role_id").ToString());
        var Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
        var IdRole = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());


        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        ...
        //File System Events to listen them
        var fileSystemEventHandler = new FileSystemEventHandler((o, e) => OnChanged(e, Idadmin, IdRole));
        watcher.Changed += fileSystemEventHandler;
        watcher.Created += fileSystemEventHandler;
        watcher.Deleted += fileSystemEventHandler;

        // Starting monitoring the folder.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        return View(watcher);
    }

    void OnChanged(FileSystemEventArgs e, int admin, int role)
    {
        using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<RhContext>();

            TraceFileManager trace = new TraceFileManager();
            trace.Adminid = admin;
            trace.Roleid = role;
            ...

            context.Add(trace);
            context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I miss that HttpContext is called from OnChanged.... I edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I trying your solution but problem persist

the full controller code is below :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using RoleBasedAuthorization.Models;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RoleBasedAuthorization.Controllers
{
    public class FileManagerController : Controller
    {

        ENAPORTALContext _context = new ENAPORTALContext();
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

        public FileManagerController(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
        {
            _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        }
        public IActionResult PQManager()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult FormulairesFManager()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult DGManager()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult DAFManager()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            ViewBag.RoleCreateur = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("role_id").ToString());
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult DAPManager()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            ViewBag.RoleCreateur = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("role_id").ToString());
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult DPCManager()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            ViewBag.RoleCreateur = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("role_id").ToString());
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult DMVManager()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            ViewBag.RoleCreateur = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("role_id").ToString());
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult PublicManager()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult DTManager()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            ViewBag.RoleCreateur = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("role_id").ToString());
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult DTPManager()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            ViewBag.RoleCreateur = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("role_id").ToString());
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult DTTManager()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            ViewBag.RoleCreateur = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("role_id").ToString());
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult SMQManager()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            ViewBag.RoleCreateur = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("role_id").ToString());
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult BoiteIdees()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            ViewBag.RoleCreateur = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("role_id").ToString());

            return View();
        }

      


        public IActionResult Documentation()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            ViewBag.RoleCreateur = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("role_id").ToString());
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult DFManager()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            ViewBag.RoleCreateur = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("role_id").ToString());
            return View();
        }
        /*     FILE MANAGER DRH*/


























        public IActionResult RHManager()
        {
            ViewBag.Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());
            ViewBag.RoleCreateur = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("role_id").ToString());
            var Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());



            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

            //Mention the Path that you want to monitor file events.

            watcher.Path = @"\\100.100.1.6\drh-m$";
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes |
            NotifyFilters.CreationTime |
            NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |
            NotifyFilters.FileName |
            NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
            NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
            NotifyFilters.Security |
            NotifyFilters.Size;
            watcher.Filter = "*.*";
            //File System Events to listen them
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

            // Starting monitoring the folder.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            return View(watcher);
        }


       

         void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ENAPORTALContext>();
                var Idadmin = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("id").ToString());     /*Admin ID variable session will be inserted into db               error : IFeatureCollection has been disposed.*/
                var RoleCreateur = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("role_id").ToString()); /*role ID variable session will be inserted into db*/
                TraceFileManager trace = new TraceFileManager();
                trace.Time = DateTime.Now;
                trace.Adminid = Idadmin;
                trace.Roleid = RoleCreateur;
                trace.Changedfile = e.Name;
                trace.Seen = false;
                trace.Etat = "En attente";
                trace.Changetype = e.ChangeType.ToString();
                _context.Add(trace);

                _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }


    










    }
}
```

Comment: It is best to edit the question to incorporate additional information, such as retrying.

Comment: If my answer answer your question, can you accept it?